# Let $X = A \cup B$. And $E \subset A \cap B$ such that $E$ is open in $A$ and that $E$ is open in $B$. Show that $E$ is open in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $X = A \cup B$. And $E \subset A \cap B$ such that $E$ is open in $A$ and that $E$ is open in $B$. Show that $E$ is open in $X$.

Since $E$ is open in both $A$ and $B$ we have that $E = A \cap U$ and $E = B \cap V$ for some $U, B$ open in $X$.

Now the claim is that $E= U \cap V$ and thus would be open in $X$ as the intersection of two open sets.

$”\subset”$ Since $E =A \cap U \implies E \subset U$ and since $E = B \cap V \implies E \subset V$ we have that $E \subset U \cap V$.

$”\supset”$  Take $x \in U \cap V$. Now since $U \cap V \subset A \cap B$ we have that $x \in A \cap U$ and that $x \in B \cap V$, but $A \cap U  = E$ and $B \cap V = E$ so $x \in E$ and $U \cap V \subset E$.

Is the $”\supset”$ part of the proof correct? I’m not entirely sure that $$x \in U \cap V \subset A \cap B \implies x \in A \cap U \text{ and } x \in B \cap V?$$

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t really used that $X=A\cup B$ yet. Use it for the proof: if $x \in U \cap V$, we have either $x \in A$ and then $x \in A \cap U = E$ or $x \in B$ and then also $x \in B \cap V = E$. So indeed $U \cap V \subseteq E$.

The other inclusion was fine, as $E \subseteq U$ and $E \subseteq V$ we have $E \subseteq U \cap V$.

Comment: This is where I had some confusion. Why is it that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ and not that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$?

Comment: @Wondera Because it’s a union, not an intersection. And $x$ is a point of $U \cap V$ so in particular a point of $X$…